# Angular - multiple http requests elegant solution

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, httprequest

I am quite new to Angular. In my project, I load different local .json files using http-requests. It works but I am asking myself, if there is a more elegant solution.

I load the local files like this:

```
// load data from file1
this.http.get("./assets/file1.json").subscribe(data => {
  this.file1 = data
})

// load data from file2
this.http.get("./assets/file2.json").subscribe(data => {
 this.file2 = data
}) 

... (repeat for every single file)
```

I need the data from every file to be stored in a separate variable (called this.file1, this.file2, ... in my example). These http requests I call in the `ngOnInit()`.

I have already tried to do something using Observables, calling a function and subscribing to the data, but I do not know how to combine that for my different files.

```
this.loadFiles().subscribe(data => {
  this.file1 = data
});

public loadFiles(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/file1.json");
}
```

I would be highly interested to see, how nice code for this task would look like.

Comment: Are you interested in combining the data from all those requests? Do they have some correlation? Also, do you pass data you get to child components?

Comment: I do not want to combine all the data. Each request should be stored in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an array of filenames, map the file names to an array of http requests. forkJoin will fire them all at once and when they have all completed the array of results will be returned in the same order as the original array.

```
const files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'];

forkJoin(files.map(file => this.http.get(`./assets/${file}.json`))).subscribe(files => {
  // do stuff with files
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your resource names are in sequence (file1, file2, file3...), you can add them to an array of observables and then use the `combineLatest` operator.

Example below shows retrieving 100 JSON objects: [refer StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-armrza?file=src/main.ts)

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(this.addObservablesIntoArray()).subscribe((data) => {
      this.files.push(...data);
      console.log(this.files);
    });
  }

  addObservablesIntoArray(): Observable<any>[] {
    let observables = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      observables.push(
        this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`)
      );
    }
    return observables;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. Unfortunately, file1, file2 were only placeholders, my variables are not named in sequence

Comment: @Robbert if is not named in sequence, you can add your resource name into an array then replace `${i}` in `addObservablesIntoArray()` with `${resourceNameArray{i}}`. `data[0]` would be your first resource, `data[1]` would be your second resource and so on..

Comment: Why would you use a for loop to build an array? Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i + 1}`))

Comment: @AdrianBrand because using loop is faster, https://jsperf.app/rusace